# How to change a MaterialTable Cell content on click?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

## Big Picture

Hi,
I'm trying to use Angular Material in Angular 7.
I have to use a Material table with some data on it. **My question is: Is there a way to change a MatCell content on click?**
For example, consider the table in HTML above, with people's name, age and phone.

#### Angular Material Table HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Phone">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort >
      
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let person" >{{person.name}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
      
    <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Age</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let person">{{person.age}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
      
    <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Phone Number</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let person">{{person.phone}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [length]="100" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

## What works

Table to diplay data, pagination, filter and sorting headers are working great!

## What I need

I want to do is **when I click in the phone cell, insted of a text, a `<input>` tag takes `{{person.phone}}` place with the current number**, allowing me to change the phone number and save the new one.
like this:

#### Desired MatCell content on click

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Phone Number</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let person">
        <input matInput [value]="person.phone"(focusout)="changePhone($event.target.value, person)" placeholder="Phone">
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf` with some kind of flag for the selected phone number to swap between the two. So for example, if you have something like this in your component:

```
selectedPerson:Person;
```

...you could have something like this in your template:

```
...
<ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Phone Number</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let person">
        <span *ngIf="selectedPerson !== person" (click)="selectedPerson = person">
            {{person.phone}}
        </span>
        <input *ngIf="selectedPerson === person" matInput [value]="person.phone"(focusout)="changePhone($event.target.value, person)" placeholder="Phone">
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
...
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!
I don't know why i did not have this idea before hahah

Comment: Glad to hear it! Good luck with your application.